# Android unable to understand kotlin function

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am not very well versed with Kotlin and I am preferring Java over Kotlin while learning Android. But I am stuck at a piece of code which is as follows:

```
private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
       val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
           File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
       return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
           mediaDir else filesDir
}
```

The following function is called in onCreate method as `var outputDirectory: File = getOutputDirectory();`

Can you please help me convert the code into Java and in understanding it?
Thank you.

Comment: The better option would be to learn the basics of Kotlin as it is the preferred language for Android development now. A lot of new blogs and tutorials will be in kotlin which would be difficult for you if you are trying using Java. And more over, there are kotlin specific things like Jetpack Compose.

Comment: Start with kotlin basics and these concepts to understand the code - "safe calls" & "scope functions".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process on how to convert Kotlin code to Java code.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-kotlin-code-to-java-code-in-android-studio/

But I suggest you to learn Kotlin as it is faster and preferred for Android app development.

Comment: This does a conversion from the byte code. In most cases, it will be more complicated and bizarre than the equivalent Java code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private File getOutputDirectory() {
        File mediaDir = null;
        if (getExternalMediaDirs().size > 0) {
            mediaDir = new File(getExternalMediaDirs()[0], getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            mediaDir.mkdirs();
        }
        
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
         mediaDir
        else 
        filesDir
        
    }
```